# Array returns undefined after promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have this script from angular. Issue is sometimes p.products shows undefined. Sometimes work sometimes not I have placed the promise in settimeout function but not resolved. `Packages Products Called 1` called successfully every time but after promise run sometimes shows p.products as undefined.

```
.directive('packagesBrowser', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        select: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'packages-browser.html',
      controller: [
        '$scope', 'Packages', 'Store', 'Inventory', function($scope, Packages, Store, Inventory) {
          $scope.packageOptions = {};
          $scope.packages = Packages;
          console.log('Packages Products Called 1');
          Packages.$promise.then(function() {
            return Packages.forEach(function(p) {
              if (!p.products) {
                return;
              }
              $scope.packageOptions[p.id] = p.products.map(function(product) {
                return {
                  product_id: product.product.id,
                  quantity: product.quantity
                };
              });
              return console.log('Packages Products Called 2');
            });
          });
          return Store.$promise.then(function() {
            return $scope.available = function(id) {
              return (Inventory.list[id] && Inventory.list[id].available) || 0;
            };
          });
        }
      ]
    };
})
```

Comment: What's the package ("p") object supposed to contain?  Maybe console.log it above the if/return for when p.products is falsy?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what `Packages` does. Apparently, whatever `Packages` contains, at least one of them does not have a `products` property.

Comment: The `array.forEach` method returns `undefined`. The `console.log` method returns `undefined`. AngularJS controllers ignore return values. One usually resolves a promise `.then` method by returning a value. In this case the value is a function. Hard to understand the intention of this code. So as to "Array returns undefined after promise", it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you are missing a parameter.. `results` in that case

try this:

```
Packages.$promise.then(function(results) {
        return results.data.forEach(function(p) {
```

Comment: This answer assumes the promise resolves with a value, which is unclear in the question. It also assumes that the value has a `data` property which is an array. Essentially, this is a guess.

Comment: Yes I agree but It might  put the OP on the right path.. Anyway I dont think my answer deserve downvote. Im just trying to help.

Comment: You have enough rep to comment; you can help by commenting, asking for more clarification of the particulars of the situation. Answers are meant for, well, answers to the question, when you know what the question is, and what the answer is.

Comment: If `Packages` is an array returned by an `ngResource`  query method, it has a property named `$promise` that resolves to `Packages`. The OPs code is correct (albeit sloppy) to do a `.forEach` on `Packages`. If it is indeed a `$resource` array, it does not have a property named `data`. Your answer is erroneous and distracts from solving the OPs problem.